# Is there a db migration tool in spring without sql query?

Tags: java, spring, flyway

I'm a python backend developer, but this time I have to use java, spring.

There is a migration tool in python, called alembic, doesn't demand knowledge of sql query, because it can be migrated without any sql query.

So, I'm finding a migration tool in spring, java, but I haven't found it yet.

Of course, I've been known flyway migration tool, but as I know, it works with sql query.

Is there a migration tool using without sql query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to flyway is liquibase. It can take in class or yml files. Here's a basic tutorial from Baeldung https://www.baeldung.com/liquibase-refactor-schema-of-java-app